# Tryinig to program arduino in pure c, get the following error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'Print'|

Tags: c++, c, arduino, codeblocks, arduino-uno

I wrote a program in the Arduino IDE (it involves some matrix math). However, I wanted to play around with some of the compiler options. There didn't seem to be an easy way to do this and so I switched to trying to write a pure c program using CodeBlocks. I got the blink example working, but I wanted to make use of the Serial library. I simply found the h and cpp files and copied them to the folder that had my main.c file. (I don't know if that was the proper way to do it).

Now I get the error message that:
 Print.h|37|error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'Print'|

The code that it is complaining about is one of the standard classes I copied.

```
/*
  Print.h - Base class that provides print() and println()
  Copyright (c) 2008 David A. Mellis.  All right reserved.

  This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
  modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
  License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
  version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

  This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
  Lesser General Public License for more details.

  You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
  License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
*/

#ifndef Print_h
#define Print_h

#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h> // for size_t

#include "WString.h"


#define DEC 10
#define HEX 16
#define OCT 8
#ifdef BIN // Prevent warnings if BIN is previously defined in "iotnx4.h" or similar
#undef BIN
#endif
#define BIN 2

class Print
{
  private:
    int write_error;
    size_t printNumber(unsigned long, uint8_t);
    size_t printFloat(double, uint8_t);
  protected:
    void setWriteError(int err = 1) { write_error = err; }
  public:
    Print() : write_error(0) {}

    int getWriteError() { return write_error; }
    void clearWriteError() { setWriteError(0); }

    virtual size_t write(uint8_t) = 0;
    size_t write(const char *str) {
      if (str == NULL) return 0;
      return write((const uint8_t *)str, strlen(str));
    }
    virtual size_t write(const uint8_t *buffer, size_t size);
    size_t write(const char *buffer, size_t size) {
      return write((const uint8_t *)buffer, size);
    }

    // default to zero, meaning "a single write may block"
    // should be overriden by subclasses with buffering
    virtual int availableForWrite() { return 0; }

    size_t print(const __FlashStringHelper *);
    size_t print(const String &);
    size_t print(const char[]);
    size_t print(char);
    size_t print(unsigned char, int = DEC);
    size_t print(int, int = DEC);
    size_t print(unsigned int, int = DEC);
    size_t print(long, int = DEC);
    size_t print(unsigned long, int = DEC);
    size_t print(double, int = 2);
    size_t print(const Printable&);

    size_t println(const __FlashStringHelper *);
    size_t println(const String &s);
    size_t println(const char[]);
    size_t println(char);
    size_t println(unsigned char, int = DEC);
    size_t println(int, int = DEC);
    size_t println(unsigned int, int = DEC);
    size_t println(long, int = DEC);
    size_t println(unsigned long, int = DEC);
    size_t println(double, int = 2);
    size_t println(const Printable&);
    size_t println(void);

    virtual void flush() { /* Empty implementation for backward compatibility */ }
};

#endif
```

My suspicion is that the problem arises because the compiler treats the code as c-code, while it is c++ code. I use the GNU AVR GCC Compiler which should be able to do both c and c++ code. Do I need to add something to my header includes to signal that it concerns c++ code?

Comment: _"Tryinig to program arduino in pure c..."_ `C` != `C++` so why the C++ tag?

Comment: Because I think the problem is caused by including the c++ libraries. I guess maybe then I shouldn't have called it pure C, but it was meant as a contrast to the 'improved c' that the arduino IDE uses.

Comment: If you include a header containing C++ code you have to use a C++ compiler and indicate that you want the file compiled as C++ by naming the file with the extension .cc or .cpp this is how gcc makes the difference. Rename you main.c as main.cpp

Comment: Changing main.c to main.cpp did indeed work, thank you! I feel kinda silly now not having thought of that. I remember having to add some kind of keyword to the import statements when using c classes from c++, somehow I had it in my head that it would the same the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are a C++ feature and don't exist in C, so the C compiler rightly gives you an error about them, since you're trying to use "pure C". Although the error is a bit confusing, what it means is that `class` isn't a keyword in C, so it thinks it's an identifier, and is confused about seeing two identifiers in a row.